# Textarea autogrow или резиновая высота

Tags: html, javascript, css

Всем доброго времени суток! Я пытаюсь сделать авторастягиваемое текстовое поле (textarea autogrow). В нете куча плагинов на jQuery, а вот нормального на чистом js найти не удалось. 
Схему я понял: При нажатии клавиши мы считаем символы в строке и если их там больше чем должно быть, увеличиваем высоту. У меня резиновая textare и я никак не могу понять как, узнать сколько символов влезет в одну строку?

Comment: на "чистом" js нету потому что никому это не надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется вам подойдет такое решение: [Textarea to resize based on content length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/textarea-to-resize-based-on-content-length)

Comment: Да, спасибо идеально подошло решение с дивом)

Answer (score 0):

```
  function adjustHeight(e) {
    const stringCount = e.target.value.split('\n').length;
    const heigth = stringCount * 25 + 'px';
    e.target.style.height = heigth;
  }
```

//html / jsx

```
      <textarea
        onKeyUp={adjustHeight}
        className={style.textarea}
      ></textarea>
```

просто считает сколько в твоем input строк и подстраивает высоту , пожалуйста